# Remove car door lock lever arm

Tags: pontiac, door, bonneville

So I am changing the door locks on a 1994 Bonneville SE because they don't work any more (pins won't allow the key to turn all the way).  My only issue right now is that I can't get this lever arm off of the old cylinder to put it on the new cylinder.  I thought that I might have to put my key in to unlock the lock to rotate it and maybe line some stuff up, but the key doesn't work (that's why I'm changing the lock).

I've linked a picture of the menacing lock rod arm and cylinder.[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing the photo it appears the retaining clip is still in place. At the 12 o'clock position you will notice a square shaped tag. Lifting the tab away  from the bracket pry the clip in the direction of the small hole that the tab sat in. Again referencing the photo this would be going up. With the amount of corrosion visible I would try to wire brush the surface and soak it with a penetrating oil like Liquid Wrench, PB Blaster, Sea Foam etc.

Comment: Excellent answer and spot on.

Comment: I didn't truly understand what you said until I went and did it. And then your explanation made perfect sense.  I ended up bending the clip trying to get it out, but the new lock came with one.  Thanks.